# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath not functioning properly in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that I use to scroll to the bottom of my collectionView

```
- (void) scrollToBottom {
    if (_messagesArray.count > 0) {
        static NSInteger section = 0;
        NSInteger item = [self collectionView:_myCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
        if (item < 0) item = 0;
        NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
        [_myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly!  I have never had a problem at any point, it works 100% consistent . . . with a modal view presentation.  If however, I push the viewController onto a navigation controller, it doesn't work.  Rather, it only works if there's over 15 cells.  Once I reach at least 15 cells, it again begins behaving perfectly.  Prior to 15 cells, it either doesn't scroll at all, or scrolls a little bit.

I realize this is a long shot, but I'm scratching my head on this one and I thought maybe somebody might know what the heck is happening.

Troubleshoots:

Have you logged to make sure it's running? YES

Have you logged index path to make sure its trying to scroll to the correct index path? YES

#### EXAMPLE

[image]

#### WORKING MODAL EXAMPLE

[image]

Comment: What's special about 15?  How big are the cells?  How many cells does it take to fill up the screen when not in a nav controller?  When in the nav controller?  What should the behavior be when the cells don't extend beyond the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @nhgrif - The cells are flexible, all different sizes.  I included a graphic so you can see.  With keyboard up, it's about 7 cells.  With keyboard down, about 15.  Once you hit 15 everything works.  Can't find anything special about either number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The NavigationController was automatically adjusting my top content inset for some reason.  I was able to prevent this behavior by adding this:

```
- (void) scrollToBottom {

    if (_isNavigationControllerVersion) {
        _myCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }

    if (_messagesArray.count > 0) {
        static NSInteger section = 0;
        NSInteger item = [self collectionView:_myCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
        if (item < 0) item = 0;
        NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
        [_myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property in `UIViewController`, and as it's inherited, in `UINavigationController`. Set it to `NO` in `self.navigationController` and it won't adjust your insets, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)

Comment: This is also one of direct reasons of weird scrolling behaviour of `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` with keyboard. If I set `contentInsets.top` to any non-zero value, the scrolling method makes scrolling *dances*(scrolled to bottom and up a bit, and down again) even in iOS 9.x. A workaround is keeping `.top` to zero with some other tricks to make space on top.

Answer (score 1):

So, since your .gif demonstrates that the problem is happening when the keyboard is open, I can only assume that the bottom scroll is within the content inset of the collection view, even if it is behind the keyboard.

Be sure you're resetting the content inset when the keyboard appears/disappears.  I will edit in some example code.

First, you need to register for the notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

This should go in `viewDidLoad`.  Don't forget to `removeObserver` in `dealloc`.

Now set the content insets in these methods:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CGSize kbSize = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    yourCollectionView.contentInset = Insets;
    yourCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = Insets;
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    yourCollectionView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    yourCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it would suddenly start working after a certain number then? I don't adjust anything else. The frame logs out properly and if I scroll, I can see the bottom properly.

Comment: Also, why would it work perfectly in a modal presentation, but not in a navigation push?

Comment: As to the former, I'm not sure.  This is kind of a guess.  As to the latter, yes, I'm not entirely sure.  I don't use UICollectionViewControllers or UITableViewControllers from storyboard.  Instead, I put the collection view or table view on a regular view controller.  And when you do this, you have to set the scroll insets as I've done.

Comment: I resize via frame, just out of preference.  I'll try hooking up this way and see if it changes.  My current insets are logging out properly.  Also, make sure you use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` as opposed to begin.  Otherwise, you'll get problems w/ asian keyboards.

Comment: I reworked everything to adjust content inset as opposed to frame, and I'm getting the exact same problem.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same issue in a context where I had access to the cell, I was able to use `scrollRectToVisible` which doesn't seem to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Yes, scrolling in `UICollectionView` seems designed to ensure that cells are on-screen, and isn't too concerned about positioning them exactly. (It also doesn't seem to take into account `contentOffset`.) Use the lower-level `-[UIScrollview scrollRectToVisible:animated:]`if the collection view scrolling isn't doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found nice solution [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController)

```
- (void)scrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
if ([self.collectionView numberOfSections] == 0) {
    return;
}

NSInteger items = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];

if (items == 0) {
    return;
}

CGFloat collectionViewContentHeight = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize].height;
BOOL isContentTooSmall = (collectionViewContentHeight < CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.bounds));

if (isContentTooSmall) {
    //  workaround for the first few messages not scrolling
    //  when the collection view content size is too small, `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:` doesn't work properly
    //  this seems to be a UIKit bug, see #256 on GitHub
    [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0, collectionViewContentHeight - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
                                    animated:animated];
    return;
}

//  workaround for really long messages not scrolling
//  if last message is too long, use scroll position bottom for better appearance, else use top
//  possibly a UIKit bug, see #480 on GitHub
NSUInteger finalRow = MAX(0, [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] - 1);
NSIndexPath *finalIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:finalRow inSection:0];
CGSize finalCellSize = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:finalIndexPath];

CGFloat maxHeightForVisibleMessage = CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.bounds) - self.collectionView.contentInset.top - CGRectGetHeight(self.inputToolbar.bounds);

UICollectionViewScrollPosition scrollPosition = (finalCellSize.height > maxHeightForVisibleMessage) ? UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom : UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop;

[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:finalIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:scrollPosition
                                    animated:animated];
}
```